# NSZombie that won't die

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access, nszombie

I am desperately reaching out for help on something that is PLAGUING me...

This is all under ARC, BTW.

I have a Profile screen (UserProfileVC) and then you click a button on that screen it presents SettingsVC.  SettingsVC is held in the settingsVC ivar of UserProfileVC, and when I respond to the button click, I check to see if settingsVC is nil, and then create it from the storyboard, and present it.

```
- (IBAction)handleSettingsButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    if (!settingsVC) {
        settingsVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UPSettingsVC"];
        settingsVC.model = self.model;
        settingsVC.horizontalCoverPresentingVC = self;
    }

    [self horizontalCoverTransitionToViewController:settingsVC duration:0.35f];
}
```

When I dismiss SettingsVC, I do nothing but remove the view from its superview (which is essentially the opposite of what the #horizontalCoverTransitionToViewController:duration: method does).  I never set it to nil.

I can navigate from UserProfileVC to SettingsVC and back... EXACTLY ONCE.  If I try to go back to SettingsVC, I hit the

```
if (!settingsVC) {...}
```

block, and do not enter it (indicating that settingsVC is still present), and then as soon as I hit

```
[self horizontalCoverTransitionToViewController:settingsVC duration:0.35f];
```

I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1...) error.

If I turn on Zombies, I can see that SettingsVC has become a Zombie.

I have even gone as far as adding -fno-objc-arc to the compiler flags for that class, then implementing #release and putting a breakpoint in it.

The release gets called from the code that dismisses the SettingsVC, but that same exact code is used by almost every other VC in my app, and none of them cause a release to fire.

Can someone give me any idea where to look, how to debug, or even some pointers on using Instruments to get at the issue??

I am beginning to suspect some underlying framework bug, but if I make a small sample app to demonstrate the issue, it works fine, so there has to be something peculiar to this class.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Have you used Xcode's analyzer? **Product > Analyze**

Comment: How are you declaring the `settingsVC` ivar?

Comment: Sadly, the analyzer shows no problems with either class (UserProfileVC or SettingsVC).  I am declaring the settingsVC in the .h as an ivar of the UserProfileVC class, not a property and with no modifiers... just SettingsVC *settingsVC;

Answer (score 2):

> If I turn on Zombies, I can see that SettingsVC has become a Zombie.

Use Instruments to record reference count operations (Allocations) -- you can enable Zombies as well. When your program halts, locate your VC in the object list, and review the recorded ref count operations for that instance. It is *usually* quite clear where the imbalance was introduced, although there may be more operations than you expect.

Comment: Hey Justin, sorry for the lame comment here.  I am sure I can get at data with your approach but have not had time to try it.  As soon as I can I will report back and accept.

Comment: Hi Justin.  Finally got a chance to play with this.  I SUCK at Instruments... it is big departure from the tools I am used to using, so I may not be looking at it properly, but what I am seeing is at the point that I click the button and the handleSettingsButtonPressed: method kicks in, the SettingsVC is created and references are incremented/decremented in what appears to be a sensible fashion.  If I examine just that object, I see the list of all retains and releases, which ends with the refCt going to 0.  There doesn't seem to be an imbalance, unless I am misreading something.

Comment: @Raconteur so if it all makes sense, then it would seem the object is being released because you hold no strong references. it would be unusual, unless your `settingsVC` were weak or the `UserProfileVC` were deallocated. so the object has been deallocated -- where can you hold a strong reference so it stays alive?

Comment: The weird thing is I am sitting on the UserProfileVC and going to the SettingsVC, then dismissing it and trying to go back.  It is the going back that causes problems.  I can try it again, but even setting the settingsVC as a strongly held property of the UPVC seemed to cause the same issue.  As a note, I have 3 other screens that are presented from UPVC in the same way and none of them have this issue, which makes me think it is in the SettingsVC, but I have even gone as far as to delete it and rebuild it in IB... to no avail.  Will try Luis' trick again and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you're not declaring the `settingsVC` ivar as a `strong` property. According to Apple's memory management rules you don't own the View Controller returned by `- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`; to own it you should declare your ivar as a strong property. Please give this a try.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) SettingsVC *settingsVC;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Luis, but sadly, no dice... still throws the same error.